# Find the coefficient of term independent of x in (1+x+7/x)^7

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

Find the coefficient of term independent of x in the expansion of $(1+x+7/x)^7$.

[image]

This is my attempt. I found the number of ways by which we can create a term independent of x.

If we take all the 1's from each bracket, there are $7C7$ ways to do that. Next we take 1 "x"from a bracket and 1 "7/x" from another bracket and take 1 from the remaining brackets, there are $7C1.6C1.7$ ways to do that. Next we take 2"x" from two brackets and 2 "7/x" from another two brackets and take 1 from the remaining brackets, there are $7C2.5C2$ ways to do that. Similarly we take 3"x" from three brackets and 3 "7/x" from other three brackets and take 1 from the remaining brackets, there are $7C3.4C3$ ways to do that.

We add all these 5 terms to get the required coefficient.

But my answer is much lesser than what is given in the textbook.

What case I missed? Did I count wrong?

[image]

Comment: There is apparently a typo in either the problem or the solution.  Note it reads "*The exponent* **11** *is to be divided...*" implying that the problem they are solving is instead $(1+x+\frac{7}{x})^{11}$ not $(1+x+\frac{7}{x})^7$

Comment: @JMoravitz Yeah that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer of $1+\binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{1}7+\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}7^2+\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{3}7^3=58605$ is correct for finding the coefficient of the constant term in the expansion of $(1+x+\frac{7}{x})^\color{red}{7}$.  [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+(1%2Bx%2B7%2Fx)%5E7)

The error is on the books part, either having a typo in the problem statement or having made a mistake in the solution itself.  The calculations in the solution are correct for the different problem of finding the coefficient of the constant term in the expansion of $(1+x+\frac{7}{x})^{\color{red}{11}}$ (*note the different exponent*).